# How to generate useful debug information in a C++/Excel environment

Tags: c++, visual-studio, excel, debugging

In many banks, people use all kind of addins mostly programmed in C++ to compute various risks and values.

My question is: considering an Excel environment with in-house Excel addins doing most of the work. Is there a format of debug information you would recommend to generate useful debug information which could be readable and avoid our developers to systematically have to debug the code using Visual Studio ?

At the moment, what I do is that in my code, I generate .csv files containing the intermediate computations in a readable format.

The files have tickers such as Risk-1-Stock-2012-08-13_8h33m00.csv which are generated on the fly and optionally produced in the temp folder. The problem is that, while it fits my purpose, it does not seem flexible enough to be used by everyone else and some other people have had their own implementations within the same project of a similar set of functions.

Maybe someone here has a 'silver bullet' which would make reporting debug information in a standard and readable format much easier ?